# JPA + Hibernate using mysql longtext unncessarily?

Tags: mysql, hibernate, jpa

I have an entity defined like so...

```
@Entity
data class MyAuthEntity(
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        val id: Long? = null,

        @Column(nullable = false, length = 500)
        @Size(max = 500)
        var token: String = "",

        @Column(nullable = false, length = 250)
        @Size(max = 250)
        var name: String = "",

...

)
```

For some reason, this generates a mysql table, defined like so...

```
CREATE TABLE `my_auth_entity` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `token` longtext NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(250) NOT NULL,

...

) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

"longtext" seems an extremely innapropriate column type for only 500 characters. Is there some valid reason why it would do this. Surely even using "text" would make more sense.

What is the correct way to get it to use varchar instead. I know I can define it like so...

```
@Column(nullable = false, length = 500, columnDefinition = "VARCHAR(500)")
```

It doesn't seem like I should have to be that implementation specific though.

Answer (score 1):

> It doesn't seem like I should have to be that implementation specific though.

To avoid having to override the `columnDefinition` on specific columns, you'll need to customize the Hibernate dialect for MySQL.

If you have a look at [`MySQLDialect`](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/master/hibernate-core/src/main/java/org/hibernate/dialect/MySQLDialect.java), you'll see the following method controlling character type resolution:

```
protected void registerVarcharTypes() {
        registerColumnType( Types.VARCHAR, "longtext" );
//      registerColumnType( Types.VARCHAR, 16777215, "mediumtext" );
//      registerColumnType( Types.VARCHAR, 65535, "text" );
        registerColumnType( Types.VARCHAR, 255, "varchar($l)" );
        registerColumnType( Types.LONGVARCHAR, "longtext" );
    }
```

in which `varchar`'s maximum capacity is set to `255`.

You'll need to override this method in a custom dialect (make sure to extend from the appropriate `MySQLXxxDialect` subclass, depending on which version of MySQL you're using), and instruct Hibernate to use your custom dialect via the `hibernate.dialect` property.